# Does Turkey stamp passport in case of visit visa rejection?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, turkey, solo-travel, female-travellers

Is a single woman allowed to travel alone to Turkey? In case of rejection do they stamp passport, or just return the passport?

This is for a Pakistani Passport Holder.

Comment: When I got a visa for Turkey, I just had to put my details into their website and pay on line, they did not have my passport so could not stamp it if they did not give me a visa.  (I live in the UK)

Comment: I think we need to know your nationality to answer this question well, voting as unclear until you edit your question to specify.

Comment: also if you a valid visa from any OECD country , you are entitled to get online visa for ordinary Pakistani passport holder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

single adult women can apply individually for Turkish visa .Turkey is a Muslim country and its requirement is different from most Muslim countries like Saudi Arabia where women cannot apply individually .Turkey nowadays adapting same visa procedure like most EU countries do.
Answer to your second question a friend of mine last year application was rejected from Karachi and he said they placed a consulate stamp and date on the very last page so presumably they would stamp your passport.
however obtaining a Turkish visa is a lot easier compare to western countries.
Just comply with the requirements and you will have  good chance getting the visa

Comment: "Turkey is a Muslim country" That depends what you mean. The overwhelming majority of Turks (96.5%, according to Wikipedia) are Muslims but, constitutionally, Turkey is a secular country.

Comment: As David said above, Turkey is NOT a "Muslim country".  It is a country where the majority of the population is Muslim, but this is very different from being a "Muslim country" like Saudi Arabia.

Comment: I rather suspect that Saudi Arabia is in the minority as far as its rules concerning women, even among Muslim countries, and even if you define that narrowly.